# Spring app on Tomcat - Application at context path /web-customer-rest-demo could not be started

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

And it's Tomcat all over again. I'm trying to run a Spring project on Tomcat, the build stage is fine, but I keep getting this deploy error. The content of config files follows:
**MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer.java**

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

**DemoAppConfig.java**

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        
        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        
        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }
    
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        
        return props;               
    }

    
    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int
    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }   
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        
        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        
        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        
        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }   
    
}
```

**Tomcat log**

```
26-Aug-2021 23:26:05.372 SEVERE [371] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\web-customer-rest-demo.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:538)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1690)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1614)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1026)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/web-customer-rest-demo]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:81)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.createServletApplicationContext(AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.registerDispatcherServlet(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
        ... 56 more
26-Aug-2021 23:26:05.377 INFO [371] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\web-customer-rest-demo.xml] has finished in [11 332] ms
```

**web-customer-rest-demo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:\Users\Егор\Documents\NetBeansProjects\web-customer-rest-demo\target\spring-crm-rest" path="/web-customer-rest-demo"/>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.luv2code.springdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-customer-rest-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.45</mysql.connector.version>
        <c3po.version>0.9.5.2</c3po.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add Jackson for JSON converters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3PO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3po.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- to compensate for java 9 not including jaxb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.9</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>spring-crm-rest</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Builds a Web Application Archive (WAR) file from the project output 
                and its dependencies. -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>web-customer-rest-demo</name>
</project>
```

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." Who made this sh*t up, I wonder?

Comment: please share the tomcat logs and app error logs

Comment: Updated the question with the Tomcat log, but where do I get app log?

Comment: something is wrong with your file web-customer-rest-demo.xml

Comment: share your web-customer-rest-demo.xml file snippet

Comment: You are missing some dependencies (e.g. `spring-core`) or you have a mixup of dependency versions.

Comment: Updated the question with that xml and pom

Comment: I _strongly_ encourage you to switch to Spring Boot, which is the modern way to develop applications. I can eliminate _the entire set of Java code_ you've provided (plus half your POM). It will _also_ keep you from mixing versions like you have with your Spring dependencies.

Comment: You were right, it was a mixup of dependencies. See that one dependency with version 5.3.9 at the end of the dependencies tag? When I removed it, it all worked. Actually I didn't add this one, it was added automatically by NetBeans that I'm using. Could you post your comment as an answer? I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: yes, Spring Boot provides hundreds of configurations to rapidly start an application. However, from a learning perspective, it shows very little of what is happening under the hood. In a first project I would even get rid of `@EnableWebMvc` and I would define those beans explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing class `org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup` belongs to `spring-core` and appeared in version 5.3.

As it appears from your `pom.xml` you have `spring-context` in version 5.3.9, which has a dependency on `spring-core` of the same version. However Maven must be choosing version `5.0.6.RELEASE`, which is a dependency of your other Spring dependencies.